# Не работает загрузка файлов через internet explorer 8

Tags: java, html, gwt

Данные вводятся в браузере на стороне клиента 8 или даже 9 -ка .
Это проблема в 8\9 версии IE.
Загрузка файла (аттач) ( картинка или любой другой файл )

Вылетает ошибка :

> com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (TypeError) - "Не удалось получить свойство "length" ссылки, значение которой не определено или является NULL"

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду ?